# How to install a software in the centOS system which is installed in the virtual machine?

Tags: centos, vmware

I downloaded a CentOS VMware file which can be played on the VMware Player. the problem for me is that I would like to install some software in the CentOS playing on the VMware player, but I don't know how to do it. I've downloaded the software package in my Win7 system. How can I call this package in the CentOS system to install?

Comment: The virtual machine doesn't have an internet connection? By the way, this question doesn't belong here; it belongs on [SU].

Comment: so u meant that just download from the internet and install?

Comment: Yes, if the virtual computer can access the outside world, that's the way to go. Otherwise, I'm not too familiar with VMWare (more with VirtualBox), but there might be a setting in the preferences to have the virtual machine see the host computer's harddrive, or one specially designated folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few simple things & then youre there. First, I would recommend configuring the networking component inside of VMWare as **bridged**. Then I would decide on using DHCP or  a static IP address for this guest. Start with DHCP since it is easy. Then, as root, or a suer with permissions, do a **/etc/init.d/network restart** and then a **ifconfig** to check that you like your TCP IP stack. You can also do a **netstat -rn** to check your default route and a **cat /etc/resolv.conf** to check your name servers. Ping a handful of things to make sure you are well connected. Then run **yum update**. Then run **yum install lynx** and then run **yum install ntpd** and then run **yum install my-stuff** as needed. If you dont know exactly what you need, run **yum search keyword** (like **yum search mysql**) to find out what you need, once you have the package name, go from there. Also know that yum allows you to install "groups" of some softwares, so ask the interwebs for advice about how to do that. Or just install them as needed until you get what you need. If this machine is critical, you will most certainly want to run **reboot** and then once it is back up again, confirm that all networking and daemons are running as you want. Last, run **chkconfig --list** for the list of daemons that start at boot time. Tweak that list to flip those **on** and **off** as you need by running a command similar to this **chkconfig ntpd on** and **chkconfig dhcpd off**.

Enjoy.